# How to debug GNU make's variable assignment

Tags: debugging, makefile

My Makefile contains something like

```
BASE_VAR=$(cat path/to/value.txt)

DERIVED_VAR=$(if $(BASE_VAR),foo,bar)
```

This does not produce the results I expected. `make --debug=a` produces detailed trace but `path/to/value.txt` doesn't appear anywhere in it. How do I debug this kind of variable assignment in a makefile?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure I understand what your trying to achieve but I suspect `BASE_VAR=$(cat path/to/value.txt)` should be `BASE_VAR=$(shell cat path/to/value.txt)` .

Comment: I don't want help debugging this particular set of variables. I want to how how I can debug how make populates its variables *in general*. Output like "executing `foo bar` and assigning 'RESULT' to VARIABLE".

Comment: Make doesn't provide anything like that.  You  just have to know how it works.  You can look at remake if you like: http://bashdb.sourceforge.net/remake/

Comment: You can run `make -p` and make will print out the final results of its parsing.  That can be helpful in some situations but won't help you solve an error like the one above.

Answer (score 0):

The problem comes from:

```
BASE_VAR=$(cat path/to/value.txt)
```

As there is not make variable or macro named `cat path/to/value.txt` the expansion
`$(cat path/to/value.txt)` produces the empty string. If you want to set variable `BASE_VAR` with the content of file `path/to/value.txt` you need the `shell` make function:

```
BASE_VAR = $(shell cat path/to/value.txt)
```

And about your question on debugging variables, the simplest in your case is probably to use the `info` make function:

```
$ cat Makefile
BASE_VAR = $(shell cat path/to/value.txt)
DERIVED_VAR = $(if $(BASE_VAR),foo,bar)

.PHONY: debug
debug:
    $(info BASE_VAR = $(BASE_VAR))
    $(info DERIVED_VAR = $(DERIVED_VAR))

$ make debug
BASE_VAR = blah
DERIVED_VAR = foo
make: Nothing to be done for 'debug'.
```

But that target-specific variables have different values in different targets. Use `$(info ...)` in the recipe of the target of interest:

```
target: VAR = value

target: ...
    $(info VAR of $@ = $(VAR))
```